# JMS Serializer Bundle ignores Entity mappings

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have my `Entity.Project.yml` file in `My/NamedBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Project.yml`

```
My\NamedBundle\Entity\Project:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            exclude: true
            type: integer
```

This is completely ignored and all attributes are being expose during serialization. What have I missed?

The documentation on this part seems vey lacking with no real example to the naming scheme used for the file or the contents of the yml file itself.

I have cleared the cache 100s of times trying to get this to work.

```
$project = $repo->find(1);
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$json = $serializer->serialize($project, 'json');
```

Updating to the container serializer results in an error

```
$serializer = $this->get("jms_serializer")
    ->configureListeners(function(EventDispatcher $dispatcher) {
        $dispatcher->addSubscriber(new MySubscriber($this->container));
    })
    ->addDefaultListeners()
    ->build();
```

> Attempted to call method "configureListeners" on class "JMS\Serializer\Serializer"

Comment: What does your generated entity look like?

Comment: @JasonRoman do you mean the generated PHP class?

Comment: Yes is like to see what the annotations look like

Comment: I am not using annotations, I am using YAML. I have no annotations set up for ORM or for the Serialization as I want to use YAML.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the code you are using to serialize the entity?

Comment: Sure thing Jason, take a look now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JMS Serializer Bundle with Symfony, correct?  Because you can avoid manually creating the builder every time and just use the service:

```
$this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($project, 'json');
```

If you still want to do this manually, try specifying your YML metadata directory when creating the serializer.  Even though your individual model files point to the full path of your entity, the serializer still doesn't know where that directory is.  Annotations don't require this because you're already inside the entity.

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/configuration

```
$serializer =
    JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()
        ->addMetadataDir('My/NamedBundle/Resources/config/serializer')
        ->build();
```

Comment: Doing that results in `You have requested a non-existent service "jms.serializer"`. Presumably if this worked then JMS Serializer would be automatically aware of my config files for exposing specific fields?

Comment: This works it seems `$this->get('serializer')` although now I am unable to call my custom handler on this new object returned from `$this->get('serializer')

Comment: yeah that's the Symfony serializer.  I had the service name wrong, it's `jms_serializer` - updated my answer to reflect this.  Try that.  And yes, presumably it should be able to be aware of your config files automatically when using this.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to call custom events now, see updated answer

Comment: You shouldn't even have to make that function call, as long as you register your listener as a Symfony service and hook the proper event, it should take care of that for you

Comment: How do I do that? Its not made obvious in the docs. I have managed without the need to exclude until now, but now I need it. Is the only way to get this to work is to use hook it up as a service corretly then load the JMS Serializer in the way you suggest, and not load the Subscriber manually myself?